# ckeditor fails to post results when with ajax save

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form set up to do a dynamic save with ajax. It works great with a standard textarea but after enabling ckeditor using the ckeditor class it does not respond. The form looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="float auto clear">
    <textarea class="ckeditor saveData" name="introtext" itemid="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="editor1" ><?php echo "$introtext"; ?></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

ckeditor is the class ckeditor uses to load the editor. saveData is the class I use to initiate the javascript function to save the textarea data. The javascript:

```
// ckeditor textarea
$(document).on('keyup','.saveData',function()
{
  var DATA = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
  var cleaned=remove_whitespaces(DATA);
  var ID=$(this).attr('itemid');
  if(cleaned !=''){
    var dataString = 'introtext='+ cleaned  +'&id='+ ID;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "save.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false
    });
  }
})
// END SAVE BASE


// ordinary textarea
$(document).on('keyup','.saveData2',function()
{
  var DATA=$(this).val();
  var cleaned=remove_whitespaces(DATA);
  var ID=$(this).attr('itemid');
  if(cleaned !=''){
      var dataString = 'introtext2='+ cleaned  +'&id='+ ID;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "save.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false
    });
  }
})
```

You can see the form at www.dottedi.us/ckeditor. I tried using both:

```
var DATA=$(this).val();
```

and

```
var DATA = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

but neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below-

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="float auto clear">
    <textarea class="ckeditor saveData" name="introtext" itemid="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="editor1" ><?php echo "$introtext"; ?></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

// ckeditor textarea
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
editor.on('change', function()
{
  var DATA = this.getData();
  var cleaned=remove_whitespaces(DATA);
  var ID=$('#editor1').attr('itemid');
  if(cleaned !=''){
    var dataString = 'introtext='+ cleaned  +'&id='+ ID;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "save.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false
    });
  }
})
// END SAVE BASE
```

Comment: That is closer but not quite working. It is not seeing ID (`var ID=$(this).attr('itemid');`) that I pass. The dataString that gets passed is: "introtext=apple pie&id=undefined". I tried calling it by a different name, $gid, $my_id and the corresponding VAR GID etc but it makes no difference. It's not taking any variable in the form line like that. For instance: `<textarea class="ckeditor saveData" name="introtext" itemid="147" my_id="147" gid="147"  ><?php echo "$introtext"; ?></textarea>`. The itemid or whatever name is required to save the correct item in the mysql table.

Comment: @BobMeetin, kindly check my updated answer this should work I tested the same above code on my machine and using the proper id - $("#editor1").attr('itemid') of the textarea you should get the values for the attribute.

Comment: By default, the 'this' references the CKEditor instance but you were trying to select the textarea to get its attribute value

Comment: That works perfectly! My knowledge of javascript is minimal if that, this helps a lot.